# get mysql_real_escape is giving me errors when I try and add security to my website

Tags: security, mysql, database, sql

I tried doing this:

```
@ $db = new myConnectDB();


$beerName = mysql_real_escape_string($beerName);
$beerID = mysql_real_escape_string($beerID);
$brewery = mysql_real_escape_string($brewery);
$style = mysql_real_escape_string($style);
$userID = mysql_real_escape_string($userID);
$abv = mysql_real_escape_string($abv);
$ibu = mysql_real_escape_string($ibu);
$breweryID = mysql_real_escape_string($breweryID);
$icon = mysql_real_escape_string($icon);
```

I get this error:

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user

Comment: Are you sure the connection was successful? Usually you get this error when there's no connection. However I think this post might be better suited for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why are you suppressing errors in the first line of code (where you presumably create the DB connection) with the `@` operator? Which MySQL extension are you using to connect to your DB?

Comment: Solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12223427/369434

Answer (score 2):

**All** of PHP's `mysql_*` functions, including [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) have been **deprecated**, in favour of the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO extensions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

See [Deprecated PHP](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/) (A blog set up by two StackOverflow members).

Use query binding (`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ?` with a $condition) and you won't have to use the function you mention.

Comment: Still lots of old application use the old mysql connector, and you might not want to refactor. This solution would not solve the problem, as the error is not thrown because the functions have been deprecated, but for other reasons (probably missing connection).